# How to use PostgreSql array type for foreign key arrays in Yesod Persistent?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, haskell, yesod, persistent

I am new to Haskell and Yesod.

I want to use Array type in PostgreSql backend, and I found that in pull request https://github.com/yesodweb/persistent/pull/884 Persistent now has support for postgres array type through **PersistArray** data constructor, (instead of Persistent's default interpretation of array as json string), but **I could not find how to use it properly** with Yesod's scaffolding.
I threw together a solution that allows me to have array of primitive types, but I cannot figure out how to enable support for "foreign key" types, e.g. type ProductId that is generated from table Product's primary key.

I am aware that simple lists can be used (e.g. list [Text]), but persistent stores it as json string, and this probably introduces overhead and prohibits native sql array operations.

Please help me find proper solution of how to use PostgreSql array type with primitive types as well as "foreign key" types.

Here's the code I came up with (I am using Yesod's scaffolding template yesodweb/postgres):

```
-- Util/PostgreSqlTypes.hs
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}

module Util.PostgreSqlTypes where

import ClassyPrelude
import qualified Data.Text as T
import Database.Persist.Types

-- https://github.com/yesodweb/persistent/blob/master/persistent-postgresql/Database/Persist/Postgresql.hs#L1109
showSqlType :: SqlType -> Text
showSqlType SqlString = "TEXT"
showSqlType SqlInt32 = "INT4"
showSqlType SqlInt64 = "INT8"
showSqlType SqlReal = "DOUBLE PRECISION"
showSqlType (SqlNumeric s prec) = concat [ "NUMERIC(", pack (show s), ",", pack (show prec), ")" ]
showSqlType SqlDay = "DATE"
showSqlType SqlTime = "TIME"
showSqlType SqlDayTime = "TIMESTAMPTZ"
showSqlType SqlBlob = "BYTEA"
showSqlType SqlBool = "BOOLEAN"
showSqlType (SqlOther (T.toLower -> "integer")) = "INT4"
showSqlType (SqlOther t) = t
```

```
-- Util/SqlArray.hs
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ExplicitForAll #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

{-# LANGUAGE InstanceSigs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

module Util.SqlArray where

import ClassyPrelude
import Database.Persist.Class
import Database.Persist.Sql
import Database.Persist.Types()
import Data.Proxy

import Util.PostgreSqlTypes(showSqlType)

newtype SqlArray a = SqlArray [a]
   deriving (Eq, Show)

unbox :: SqlArray a -> [a]
unbox (SqlArray a) = a

instance PersistField a => PersistField (SqlArray a) where
   toPersistValue (SqlArray array) = PersistArray $ map toPersistValue array

   fromPersistValue (PersistArray array) = Right $ SqlArray $ rights $ map fromPersistValue array
   fromPersistValue (PersistList array) = Right $ SqlArray $ rights $ map fromPersistValue array
   fromPersistValue _ = Left "SqlArray values must be converted from PersistArray or PersistList"

instance PersistFieldSql a => PersistFieldSql (SqlArray a) where
   sqlType :: forall v. PersistFieldSql v => Proxy (SqlArray v) -> SqlType
   sqlType _ = SqlOther $ showSqlType (sqlType (Proxy :: Proxy v)) <> " ARRAY"
```

```
-- Util/SqlArrayOperators.hs
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Util.SqlArrayOperators where

import ClassyPrelude
import Database.Persist.Class
import Database.Persist.Types
import Util.SqlArray

infix 4 @>., <@.
(@>.) :: PersistField a => EntityField record (SqlArray a) -> [a] -> Filter record
(@>.) field arr = Filter field (FilterValue $ SqlArray arr) $ BackendSpecificFilter " @> "

(<@.) :: PersistField a => EntityField record (SqlArray a) -> [a] -> Filter record
(<@.) field arr = Filter field (FilterValue $ SqlArray arr) $ BackendSpecificFilter " <@ "
```

Example usage:

```
-- Model.hs
import Util.SqlArray
share [mkPersist ...

-- models.persistentmodels
...
Options
    Id Text
    optType OptionTypeId
    list (SqlArray Text)
...

-- Request handler code
...
-- options :: [Text]
runDB $ selectList [ OptionsList @>. options, ...] [ ... ]
...
```

Answer (score 1):

There was some confusion among Persistent's maintainers about what https://github.com/yesodweb/persistent/pull/884 was accomplishing. It was just intended for filter queries, and doesn't provide full support. Some of the limitations are discussed here: https://github.com/yesodweb/persistent/pull/1077

That said, if your approach is working for types like `Text`, I'm not sure why it wouldn't work for types like `ProductId`